# SQL Server Filter data from 1 column and and create 4 new columns depended on the filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT[EntityContactPointID]
  ,[EntityKeyID]
  ,[ContactTypeLookupID]
  ,[Value]
FROM [ASTRO_STAGE].[dbo].[tr_EntityContactPoints]

EntityContactPointID EntityKeyID  ContactTypeLookupID  Value
1234                  9                  130            +123456789
1235                  9                  129            email@contoso.com
1236                  9                  128            fax phone number(123456)
1237                  9                  127            office phone number(123456)
1229                  8                  130            +123456789
1230                  8                  129            email@contoso.com
1231                  8                  128            fax phone number(123456)
1232                  8                  127            office phone number(123456)
```

I am trying to export the data but i want them to export on different columns so I do not have 4 times the same user. I am wondering how can i create the query.

Comment: What is your qusetion here, you haven't asked one. "I want" isn't a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT EntityKeyID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTypeLookupID = 130 THEN VALUE END) as col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTypeLookupID = 129 THEN VALUE END) as col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTypeLookupID = 128 THEN VALUE END) as col3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTypeLookupID = 127 THEN VALUE END) as col4
FROM [ASTRO_STAGE].[dbo].[tr_EntityContactPoints]
GROUP BY EntityKeyID;
```

You haven't specified the names that you want for the columns, so I just chose arbitrary names.

Comment: Just a comma after EntityKeyID and all is great :)

Comment: You are great Thank you I tried with case before but didn't work for me without the MAX in front. Now works and thank you very much for your help.